# How to get controller action in magento?

Tags: url, ajax

make one module

using that module i add tab in order view now when i m click on button that time in url 404 accours

module name: orderattachments

controller name: orderattachments

Action name: save

my url:

```
 url: '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('orderattachments/adminhtml/orderattachments/save')?>'
```

what is wrong in my url

config.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <File_OrderAttachments>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </File_OrderAttachments>
</modules>

<global>
<models>
        <orderattachments>
            <class>File_Orderattachments_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>orderattachments_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </orderattachments>
         <orderattachments_mysql4>
            <class>File_Orderattachments_Model_Mysql4</class>
             <entities>
                <orderattachments>
                    <table>order_attachments</table>
                </orderattachments>
            </entities>
        </orderattachments_mysql4>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <orderattachments>
            <class>File_OrderAttachments_Block</class>
        </orderattachments>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <orderattachments>
            <class>File_OrderAttachments_Helper</class>
        </orderattachments>
    </helpers>  
    <resources>
        <orderattachments_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>File_OrderAttachments</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </orderattachments_setup>
        <orderattachments_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </orderattachments_write>
        <orderattachments_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </orderattachments_read>
    </resources>
</global>      
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <orderattachments before="Mage_Adminhtml">File_OrderAttachments_Adminhtml</orderattachments>
                </modules>
                <frontName>orderattachments</frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <orderattachments>
                <file>orderattachments.xml</file>
            </orderattachments>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

OrderattachmentsController.php

```
 <?php
 class File_OrderAttachments_Adminhtml_OrderattachmentsController extends    Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 {


public function saveAction()
{
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])))
    {
        try {   
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['file']['name'] );
            $data['file'] =$path.$_FILES['file']['name'];
            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            echo $fileName;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {}     
    }

    $orderId = $_SESSION['id'];
    $con = Mage::getModel('orderattachments/orderattachments');
    $con->setData('order_id', $orderId);
     if (!empty($fileName)) 
    {       
        $con->setData('file', $fileName);   
    }
    $con->save();

}
```

}

Comment: Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('orderattachments/orderattachments/save');

Comment: not working again 404 error

Comment: can you plase show config.xml file

Comment: Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/orderattachments_orderattachments/save')

Comment: Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: please help me..

Comment: remove                 <frontName>orderattachments</frontName>

Comment: 404 error                                                         Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/magento19/index.php/admin/orderattachments_orderattachments/s%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bave/key/207d860db77685167fd21604d8e23297/

Answer (score 2):

there lot of issue in you extension  tag is  not closed at config.xml.
Also,There lot issue in you module.

config.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <File_OrderAttachments>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </File_OrderAttachments>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <orderattachments>
        <class>File_OrderAttachments_Helper</class>
      </orderattachments>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <orderattachments>
        <class>File_OrderAttachments_Block</class>
      </orderattachments>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <orderattachments>
        <class>File_OrderAttachments_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>orderattachments_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </orderattachments>
      <orderattachments_mysql4>
        <class>File_OrderAttachments_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>        
              <orderattachments>
                <table>order_attachments</table>
              </orderattachments>
        </entities>
      </orderattachments_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <orderattachments_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>File_OrderAttachments</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </orderattachments_setup>
      <orderattachments_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </orderattachments_write>
      <orderattachments_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </orderattachments_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <File_OrderAttachments before="Mage_Adminhtml">File_OrderAttachments_Adminhtml</File_OrderAttachments>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <orderattachments module="orderattachments">
        <title>OrderAttachments</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <orderattachments module="orderattachments">
            <title>Manage Orderattachments</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/orderattachments</action>
          </orderattachments>
        </children>
      </orderattachments>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <orderattachments translate="title" module="orderattachments">
              <title>OrderAttachments</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <orderattachmentsbackend translate="title">
            <title>Backend Page Title</title>
          </orderattachmentsbackend>
          <orderattachments translate="title">
            <title>Manage Orderattachments</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          </orderattachments>
              </children>
            </orderattachments>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <orderattachments>
          <file>orderattachments.xml</file>
        </orderattachments>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

You can get url by `Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/orderattachments/save');`
means

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/controllername
/action');
```

Comment: in your config there is menu that is not needed in my project i have to add tab in order view

Comment: Then just remove it from <menu> .... </menu>